# Magento 2: Product attribute is not get any value in observer

Tags: magento2, attributes, event-observer

Here am using if condition to redirect if product attribute option value is !5431 but attribute is not echo any value here.

```
<?php

namespace Softadroit\Prescription\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Event\Observer as EventObserver;
use Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager;
use Psr\Log\LoggerInterface;

class Orderplaceafter implements ObserverInterface
{
    protected $_responseFactory;
    protected $_url;
    protected $_order;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\ResponseFactory $responseFactory,
        \Magento\Framework\UrlInterface $url,
        \Magento\Sales\Api\Data\OrderInterface $order
    ) {
        $this->_responseFactory = $responseFactory;
        $this->_url = $url;
        $this->_order = $order;
    }
    
    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
    {       
        $event = $observer->getEvent();
        $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
        $_checkoutSession = $objectManager->create('\Magento\Checkout\Model\Session');
        $_quoteFactory = $objectManager->create('\Magento\Quote\Model\QuoteFactory');
                        
        $orderid = $observer->getEvent()->getOrderIds();
        $order = $this->_order->load($orderid);
        
        foreach($order->getItemsCollection() as $_item){        
        $product = $_item->getProductId();          
        //echo $_item->getName(); die();
        
        //$is_priscription =  $_item->getProduct()->getMyCustomAttribute('prescription');       
        
        //echo $_item->getProduct()->getMyCustomAttribute('prescription');
        //die();
        
        $is_priscription = $_item->getProduct()->getAttributeText('prescription');
        
        //echo "call";
        //echo $_item->getProduct()->getPrescription();
        //exit;
        
        if($is_priscription == "" && $is_priscription != '5431'){
             $redirectionUrl =  $this->_url->getUrl('order-success');
             $this->_responseFactory->create()->setRedirect($redirectionUrl)->sendResponse();
             //return $this;
              return;
            }
        }       
        
        $order = $_checkoutSession->getLastRealOrder();
        $quote = $_quoteFactory->create()->loadByIdWithoutStore($order->getQuoteId());
        
        if ($quote->getId()) {
            $quote->setIsActive(1)->setReservedOrderId(null)->save();
            $_checkoutSession->replaceQuote($quote);
            $url = $this->_url->getUrl('prescription/index'); //('[ModuleName]/[ModuleName]/[[Action]');
            $this->_responseFactory->create()->setRedirect($url)->sendResponse();
            die();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Just add echo "call";exit; and check it file call or not.

Comment: Try  echo $_item->getProduct()->getData('prescription');

Comment: @RohanHapani Call get echo

Comment: @HamendraSunthwal this display some other data but not attribute value

Comment: echo $_item->getProduct()->getPrescription();

Comment: @ArunKumar Check the answer and let me know working for you.

Comment: Its working now, I want here **if product attribute option value is !5431 then redirect to ```$redirectionUrl =  $this->_url->getUrl('order-success');``` url

And if attribute option value is == 5431 then redirect to ```$url = $this->_url->getUrl('prescription/index'); ``` This url
I updated code above please have a look

Comment: It seems like 5431 is option id. you can use code my answer. Mark as accepted so, it will useful for others :)

Comment: Yes it is option id, Ya I will accept the answer. Please help me out with above comment I also updated code above

Comment: Try to use this code for redirect : $url = $this->_urlInterface->getUrl('order-success');

        $observer->getControllerAction()
                    ->getResponse()
                    ->setRedirect($url);

Comment: Actually the above code is redirect both the conditions to order-succes, but I only want to redirect ``` if( $is_priscription != '5431')``` this condition

Comment: @RohanHapani Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the below code :

To get attribute object :

```
$attribute = $_item->getProduct()->getResource()->getAttribute('your-attribute-code'); // It will return attribute object.
```

To get attribute option id :

```
$attribute->getSource()->getOptionId('your-attribute-option-label');
```

To get attribute value :

```
echo $_item->getProduct()->getResource()->getAttribute('your-attribute-code')->getFrontend()->getValue($_item->getProduct());
```